# Advice on Server Solution for small business?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, vps, packages

We are a small business looking to change server and I am not the most knowledgeable in this field so I was hoping some of you had some suggestions or some knowledge and expertise that can at least help point me in the right direction.

We build WordPress custom themes for websites, Shopify sites, sites using Laravel & Woocommerce sites. We currently have around 20-30 sites sitting on a VPS server with UK Fast. This server is an '[eCloud Public](https://www.ukfast.co.uk/ecloud-public.html)' Server and the specs are below:

Total processors: 2

Processor #1
Vendor
GenuineIntel
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
20480 KB

Processor #2
Vendor
GenuineIntel
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
20480 KB

HDD: 75GB

HDD: 10GB

Memory: 4GB

CPU: 2

Our Average RAM Usage over past month : 71.5867% 
And Average CPU Usage over past month : 19.329%

It is a Linux server.

We are wanting to move from this server and migrate to a new one. We don't mind if it is still with UK fast or not but we are looking for:

- As low cost as possible
- If a site gets infected, it won't affect the other sites on the server (unable to spread)
- Fast Loading websites (I h=know this isn't all down to the server but our current one is a tad slow)
- Good security

at the moment it costs £147 / month

Does anyone know if we are using the right package or if some other service would suit us better?

I am just looking for advice as I have little idea when it comes down to servers.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too wide a question to fit the format of this site, but some general tips:

- You need to understand your environment to judge what will give you the best bang for the buck when it comes to speed. A wild guess is that paying for SSD storage instead of mechanical HDDs would make a difference. If a lot of your activity is database traffic, increasing RAM (and configuring the database engine(s) to make use of it) may make a difference.
- Security is not something you buy and bolt on. It's achieved by understanding your products and continuously working according to sane practices.